# connection refused exception in socket programming

Tags: java

In simple socket programming in java , what ip should be given while making new socket and its on wan

//Server side

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8888);
System.out.println("\n\n\tWaiting for connection\n");
Socket c = ss.accept();
System.out.println("\n\n\tConnection established\n");

//Client side
Socket c=new Socket("192.16*****",8888);
System.out.println("\n\n\tSuccessfully connected to the server");

//in **** there is complete ip address of my computer .... i.e. IPV4 address (checked 

//from ipconfig command on cmd)
```

Comment: could you comment on what your problem is except that it is refused.

Answer (score 1):

By default, a new `ServerSocket` should bind to all network interfaces.
You should be able to find out what interfaces are being used by running (I assume you're running Windows, since you mentioned ipconfig):

```
netstat -an |find /i "8888"
```

If in fact the application is creating a socket and binding to all interfaces, you should see an entry like the following:

```
TCP   0.0.0.0:8888   0.0.0.0:0   LISTENING
```

Otherwise, you should be able to get the interface that is being used (it's the first IP address from the left).